# ¿como mostrar elementos fuera de un moda?

Tags: html, bootstrap

### Duda resuelta

---

¿Cómo puedo hacer que fuera de un modal puede mostrarse información?
lo estaba haciendo de esta manera ya que necesito que se vea en la parte superior pero no se como puedo quitar el fondo del modal, gracia por su atencion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
<div class="modal fade align-items-center" id="modalvacunas" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalvacunasLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 8em!important;">
    <span class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">❗</span>
    <div class="alert alert-light border-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <span><strong>Atención:</strong> Si no cuenta con la fecha de aplicación el sistema pondra la fecha de hoy.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header" id="headervacunas">
            <h5 id="form-vacuna" class="modal-title">Actualizar vacuna</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-idvacuna" style="display:none;">
            <p>Seleccionar una vacuna:</p>

            <select name="vacuna" id="lista-vacuna" class="form-control">
                <?php foreach ($vacunasEspecie as $key => $value) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->iIdVacuna; ?>"><?php echo $value->vNombre; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>



            <br>
            <p>Agrega la nueva fecha:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="fecha-aplicacion">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ActualizarVacuna()">Actualizar</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si te referías a algo así? Con un alert podría quedar bien. Se diferencia perfectamente del resto del modal. Usé Bootstrap 5.2. Espero te sirva.
[Link de la documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/alerts/#examples)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalvacunas">
  Mostrar Modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalvacunas" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalvacunasLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="alert alert-warning text-center" role="alert">
  ¿Por qué no usar un alert?
</div>

<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-success" id="headervacunas">
            <h5 id="form-vacuna" class="modal-title">Actualizar vacuna</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-idvacuna" style="display:none;">
            <p>Seleccionar una vacuna:</p>

            <select name="vacuna" id="lista-vacuna" class="form-control">
                <?php foreach ($vacunasEspecie as $key => $value) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->iIdVacuna; ?>"><?php echo $value->vNombre; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>



            <br>
            <p>Agrega la nueva fecha:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="fecha-aplicacion">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ActualizarVacuna()">Actualizar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, listo si me ayudo mucho tu ejemplo así me quedo a mi

Comment: Me da gusto! Saludos.